# Async / Await - Order of Operations not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

## Overview

I am working in a react app using redux. I have an action that checks wether or not we have new image data. If so, it will upload it, receive the new URL and then use this data to update the object.

## Problem

However, the order of operations within my function are working as expected, however code outside the function runs before it is completed.

## Question

Why is my console log at the bottom executing before the contents of my async function are completed?

```
if(imageData) {
      const imageGUID = guid();
      const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(`${imageData.name}_${imageGUID}`);
      // This function should complete before the console log at the bottom is called.
      await storageRef.put(imageData).on('state_changed', snap => {
        }, async (err) => {
          console.log(err)
          toastr.error("Uh Oh!", `Could not upload image`);
        }, async () => {
          imageURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
          console.log("NEW IMAGE URL: ", imageURL);
          
      })
    }
    console.log("Done setting up new image: ", imageURL) // This is called before we get the IMAGE URL from Firestore.... why?
```

Comment: What can I do here to wait until I get the call back?

Comment: What is `storageRef.put`? Does its `.on()` method return a promise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.on` function does not return a Promise so there is nothing to wait for the `await`. You have to convert the event base API of `put` to a Promise.

```
if (imageData) {
  const imageGUID = guid();
  const storageRef = projectStorage.ref(`${imageData.name}_${imageGUID}`);
  // This function should complete before the console log at the bottom is called.
  try {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      storageRef.put(imageData)
        .on('state_changed', snap => {},
          reject, resolve)
    })

    imageURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
    console.log("NEW IMAGE URL: ", imageURL);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    toastr.error("Uh Oh!", `Could not upload image`);
  }
}
console.log("Done setting up new image: ", imageURL)
```

Answer (score 0):

`storageRef.put(imageData).on` - doesn't look like promise (you upload your image in callback), so `await` doesn't make sense

If you want to use promises, you should write it something like that

```
 await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      storageRef
        .put(imageData)
        .on('state_changed', snap => {
        }, async (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          toastr.error('Uh Oh!', `Could not upload image`);
          reject()
        }, async () => {
          imageURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();
          console.log('NEW IMAGE URL: ', imageURL);
          resolve()
        });
    })
```

Comment: Having `async` within `new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{ … })` is an anti-pattern. The `imageURL = await storageRef.getDownloadURL();` should be outside of `new Promise …` and `async` within in it should be removed.